# What is UDDI and its uses?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, uddi, juddi

I searched for UDDI but did not understand it very well. Is it an online guide to listing web services?

I want to explain a practical example (jUDDI) around it and also its relationship with WSDL and SOAP in web services.

Answer (score 1):

From the moment a Web Services is created, a company must be able to make it available and conversely, the developers must be able to find it. The discovery of a Web Services is an essential step because it is on this occasion that we will be able to recover the WSDL contract without which nothing would be possible. As a result of this need, Ariba, IBM, and Microsoft started the development of the Universal Description, Discovery and Integration (UDDI) standard, which is generally accepted and then rejected by OASIS, with the aim of providing a standard way to publish and query the Web  Services. The UDDI specification adopts a distributed virtual directory approach that allows a user,
 via a web interface, to publish or search a Web Services. UDDI is for simplicity comparable to a  traditional paper phone book (in addition to complete

[image: the three facets of the UDDI directory]

• White pages: include the list of companies and information associated with them
 (contact information, company description, identifiers ...).

• The yellow pages: list the web services of each company under the WSDL standard.

• Green Pages: provide accurate technical information about the services provided.

**Types of data structure (UDDI register)**

Registering a web service involves four types of essential data structures: business information, service information, link information, and information describing service specifications. The relationships between these types of data are described in Figure.

• Business Information: Information contained in a businessEntity structure. The businessEntity structure contains information about the company that published the service, such as the name, description, contacts, and identifiers of that company.

• Service Information: Information describing a group of web services. They manage in a businessService structure. The businessService structure contains information about the technical service families. It groups together a set of Web services associated with a business process or a service group.

• Binding Information: Information represented by the BindingTem-plate structure. The bindingTemplate structure holds technical information for determining the entry point and build specifications for calling a web service. It provides Web service descriptions useful to application developers who want to find and call a web service. The bindingTemplate structure points to implementation descriptions of a service, for example, through a URL.

• Information describing the service specifications: The aerial metadata for the various specifications implemented by a given web service are represented by the tModel structure. tModel provides a reference system that facilitates the recognition of web services.